# How to fetch all gmail profile details with oauth?

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I want to fetch my users gmail profile details like phone, time zone, city, contacts, emails, chats and every thing else.

Is it possible to do it with oauth or I should use from something else?

And please guide me how to use oauth or your suggested library.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you have a slight confusion regarding the use of OAuth.

First, OAuth is an authentication protocol which some of Google's APIs support. It is used to verify credentials in a safer and departmentalized way. Meaning that the user can grant limited access to a third party application. The application access can be limited to one or more services.

Note that not all Google APIs support OAuth authentication.

You can read more about Google-OAuth here: 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Second, to access the information you want you probably need to use the **Admin SDK** which includes the **Email Audit API**

> The Google Apps Email Audit API allows Google Apps administrators to audit a user's email, email drafts, and archived chats. In addition, a domain administrator can retrieve account login information and download a user's mailbox.

This excerpt is from here, where you can read more about this API:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#accessing_account_information

I did not use it myself, but as I understand it, the Admin SDK gives you access to most if not all the information you need. So in case you need to access more information, just look for other Google APIs. Here a list of Google APIs where you can start looking: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/